# Compatibility of graphics card with my PC

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, pci-express, graphics

I have a 4GB RAM PC with 2.6GHz processor and it has PCIx16 slot available. I am checking if it is possible to install 8GB graphics 2.5GHz NVIDIA card to the motherboard.

1. Does 8GB graphics card 2.5GHz mean, it requires min. 8GB RAM, 2.5GHz in my PC as well?
2. Also it has DDR5, so does it work? Because my PC is working with DDR4 RAM.

I am not familiar with PC hardwares, I am asking for my brother. Just curious about the compatibility factors, because in internet, I read like you need to ensure only free PCIx16 slot and PSU power requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I read like you need to ensure only free PCIx16 slot and PSU power requirement.

That's mostly true, with the exception of pairing very old motherboards with new graphics cards. The newer models seem to not support PCIe 1.0.

Your PC has very little RAM though and it you want to play modern games on it, this will be a major bottleneck. 8 GB is a minimum for comfortable everyday usage these days, not to mention gaming. Games will be starving for RAM before the GPU gets anywhere near its top performance. I'd suggest upgrading to at least 8 GB of RAM first - ideally 16 GB if you can afford it. You may realize that you don't need a graphics card upgrade yet because your PC is already bottlenecked by lack of available RAM.

Answer (score 1):

> Does 8GB graphics card 2.5GHz mean, it requires min. 8GB RAM, 2.5GHz in my PC as well?

It does not. But @gronostaj is correct; you should really buy more RAM.

You won't be able to use your GTX1070 to its full potential unless you upgrade your RAM (and possibly other components as well).

> Also it has DDR5, so does it work? Because my PC is working with DDR4 RAM.

A DDR5 video card can still run on a system with DDR4 RAM.